# Unable to delete .swp file

Tags: windows, vim, powershell

I'm using Vim on Windows 7 Enterprise. Vim sometimes creates an `.swp` file. After closing Vim, this file sticks around. I would like to delete it. However, I receive the following error:

```
ri : Cannot remove item
C:\.someFile.txt.swp:
You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ ri .someFile.txt.swp
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\.someFile.txt.swp:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Vim is closed and I am using an admin PowerShell prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Aha. I needed to use the `-force`.

```
remove-item .someFile.txt.swp -force
```

The comprehensive answer is:

- Use an admin PowerShell prompt.
- Ensure Vim is closed.
- Use the `-force`

Comment: The obvious pun is too too tempting. "May the -force be ..." :-)
or 
"Use the -force, Shaun, Use the -force!!!"

Comment: And yet, this failed for me.  All the MSYS shells are not running, at least not as processes.  I don't know if there's some latent service running which shares a dll with something vim used, which doesn't properly release the file.  vim is not running.  MSYS shell is not running.  Nothing else is accessing this file.  I can't even take ownership of the file, which I created.  :s  But wait, there was a vim running even though not attached to the shell anymore, but even after killing that, the file remains untouchable. ... And then it magically disappeared after a short while.